R - sf::st_within not returning any match despite clear overlap
I am trying to "filter" my sf object of multipolygons by latitude. I am using the answer provided here to do so: How to filter sfc polygons by long/lat values?
I have my sf object of interest and a bounding box created with a latitude maximum of 36°30’, resulting from the following code:
library(tidyverse)
library(tidycensus)
library(sf)

# download the sf object in question
cbsa_22 <- get_acs(
  geography = "cbsa",
  variables = c(total_pop_22 = "B01003_001"),
  geometry = T,
  year = 2022,
  survey = "acs5",
  output = "wide"
) 

# create bounding box
filt_bbox <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -180,
                       xmax = 180,
                       ymin = -90, 
                       ymax = 36.5), 
                     crs = st_crs(cbsa_22)) %>% 
  st_as_sfc(.)



When I plot cbsa_22 and filt_bbox, they clearly overlap.
plot of the two objects
But when I run the following code to get the multipolygon objects that are within filt_bbox, I am returned a sgbp object with all 0's, when I expect a significant number of 1's.
cbsa_22_S <- st_within(cbsa_22, filt_bbox)

cbsa_22_S1 <- cbsa_22[which(lengths(cbsa_22_S) != 0), ]
# returns sf object of 0 observations


Am I doing something wrong, or is it a st_within problem? Is there a solution?

Do you have spherical geometry turned on? By default, sf usually does. When I run sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE) followed by the code you've provided, it returns a simple features data.frame of 350 observations. When plotting with ggplot2, it confirms to return the CBSAs contained within the bounding box.

@cristian-vargas That did the trick -- thank you!
